# Imagick/Ghostscript alternative for converting pdf to jpg

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

I'm trying to convert pdf files into jpg-format using imagick/ghostscript (v9.10, obviously the latest built for ubuntu 14.04) and php. Unfortunately imagick keeps removing special characters like **é** or **ö**. I assume missing fonts are responsible for this type of behaviour. I receive the PDF files from dozens different companies and they often change their used fonts. Thus i'm not able to import any of the used fonts.
I'd like to convert pdf to jpg (or png) and resize it a bit, thats all. Is there another possible sollution not requiring ghostscript?
Edit: source code

```
foreach(glob("$files_temp*.pdf") as $globpdf){
            $imagick = new Imagick(); 
            $imagick->readImage($globpdf);
            $imgname=basename($globpdf,".pdf");
            $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(25);
            $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');

            $imagick->writeImage($files_img.$imgname.'.jpg');
            $imgsql=$imgname.'.jpg';
            }
```

Comment: You should at first show your exact command line which you are using. That way, somebody eventually could give you hints or solve the problem. Your last question is way too broad. There are dozens of such solutions. For example, you could display the PDF file in your PDF reader, take a screenshot and convert that to JPG ...

Comment: Not the actual answer, but perhaps useful: It is possible to copy TTF fonts (from a Windows machine) to your Linux box and make them known to Ghostscript. I did this once many years ago, so I know it works, but I really can't remember the exact steps. By the way, if the PDFs you receive don't have all their fonts embedded, you'll run into problems anyway (letting aside the problems with special characters) because the (converted) files won't look like the original ones.

Comment: @Binarus, thanks for your reply. I added the code. I don't know why but the created jpg looks exactly like the pdf file - except the missing specialchars. There is just blank space, not a bordered square or anything like that.

Comment: Since I don't know PHP and Ubuntu, I could only give that final advice: I think PHP uses ImageMagick under the hoods, so to debug the problem further, you could use ImageMagick directly (you'll have to figure out the required command line switches yourself :-)). If that works, you know that the problem is in PHP or the PHP ImageMagick library, but not in ImageMagick itself, and you eventually could write a simple shell script which does what you want (without using PHP).

Comment: One last hint: I once had a complicated mass image converting task and tried to solve it using ImageMagick. I did thorough tests and saw that ImageMagick was misbehaving in many situations. I then switched to GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick and had no problems since then. So if you would be willing to try bash scripts instead of PHP, you could try GraphicsMagick (eventually, PHP has an implementation of GraphicsMagick so that you could continue to use PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Its not really going to be possible to comment thoroughly on this without seeing an example file which causes you problems. Note that you don't actually need IM at all for this conversion, Ghostscript is perfectly capable of rendering to a JPEG on its own.

Binarus is completely correct that if your PDF files do not contain all the fonts they need then you **will** have problems rendering them, no matter what tool you use. Its possible that these may be more or less exaggerated in different applications, but whenever you substitute fonts, the result is incorrect. So you should make some effort to educate your users, get them to create PDF files with the fonts embedded, then you won't have so many problems.

Having said all that, you are using a rather elderly version of Ghostscript. 9.10 is 4 years old, and its entirely possible that there have been improvements to the missing font substitution in that time (in fact, I know there have). I understand a desire to stick with a LTS version but seriously, you need to think about upgrading.

There are, of course, other PDF rendering tools, I might suggest Poppler or MuPDF or Evince. But all of those will presumably be old versions as well on your old Linux, and in any event will likely suffer from the same problem as any other PDF consumer, if the fonts aren't available, then there will be output problems.

If you make an example available then I'll look into what the actual problem is, and compare the 9.10 result with current code, but without that, there's nothing to go on.